# How do I sort monthly payment data based on the month that has been paid

Tags: php

I want to sort the monthly payment data according to the order of the month that has been paid. For example, Eliza has paid her bills for January and March. Which means, he hasn't paid his bill for February, right? Well, I want the data to be displayed in a table like the one below.

[image: image 1]

Here is my current code.

```
<?php foreach($clientid as $cid): ?>
  <?php $cekmonth = $this->db->get_where('tb_months',['month_id' => $cid['ps_month']])->row_array(); ?>
  <?php $listmonths = $this->db->get('tb_months')->result_array(); ?>
  <?php foreach($listmonths as $lm): ?>
    <?php if($lm['month_id'] == $cid['ps_month']) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $cekmonth['month_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($cid['ps_date'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cid['ps_total']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <?php }else { ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the result of my current code.

[image: image 2]

This is the content of the client's monthly bill payment database.

[image: image 3]

Comment: What data is in the clientid?

Comment: The client's monthly bill payment data and I will display it in the table above based on the client id. Maybe I'll update my post again, and add a view of the database contents of the clientid. @MostafaNZ

Comment: There are 12 records in the tb_months table?

Comment: Ya, there are 12 records in the tb_months table.

Comment: The loop related to the month is executed twice. Because there are two items in $clientid. It means 24 months. The first loop should be removed. Compare the information with the array inside the loop related to the month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you have given, you can modify the code in this way. Modify the `$cekmonth` array structure according to your needs.

```
<?php 
    $cekmonth ;
    foreach($clientid as $cid) {
        $cekmonth[$cid['ps_month']] = $this->db->get_where('tb_months',['month_id' => $cid['ps_month']])->row_array();
    }
?>
  <?php $listmonths = $this->db->get('tb_months')->result_array(); ?>
  <?php foreach($listmonths as $lm): ?>
    <?php if(isset($cekmonth[$lm['month_id']]) { ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $cekmonth['month_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($cid['ps_date'])); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $cid['ps_total']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <?php }else { ?>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Wow amazing. It worked. Thank you.  It's just that there is an error in the month name column. A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: month_name

Comment: Replace this code : `$cekmonth[$lm['month_id']]['month_name']`